# Reason generalized linear model

Tags: statistics, variance, means

Often one says that the Generalized linear models are 'invented' such that it is possible that the variance depends on the mean. Unfortunatly , I can't find a real-life example where this is wanted. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Take for instance the Poisson regression, when if there is no over-dispersion, you expect the mean to be equal the variance. So, if this kind model really fits your data, the realm of possible application is enormous. For instance, the [Challenger data](http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/people/bloomfield/courses/ST370/Slides/MandR-ch11-sec10-10.pdf).